# Powershell Dynamic Menu Based on Mailbox Permission Entries

Tags: powershell

I'm having trouble with creating a dynamic menu from mailbox permission entries in PowerShell.  The below function gets a list of permission entries for the selected mailbox and outputs a table.

```
Function AuditSingleMailboxPermission($mbox) {
If ($mbox -like $null){
    Write-Host "Please select the mailbox from the list below"
    $mbox = SelectMailbox
  }

  $mboxPermissions = Get-MailboxPermission $mbox | where {$_.User -like "*@*"}
  Return $mboxPermissions
}
```

The next function uses the output of the previous to build the menu.

```
Function SelectMailboxPermission($mbox) {
$rights = (AuditSingleMailboxPermission -mbox $mbox).User
Write-Host $rights
$menu = @{}
  for ($i=1;$i -le $rights.count; $i++) {
    Write-Host "$i. $($rights[$i-1])"
    $menu.Add($i,($rights[$i-1]))
  }
  [int]$ans = Read-Host "Enter selection"
  $selection = $menu.Item($ans)
  Return $selection
}
```

The Write-Host $rights line shows the full username.  However, the menu only returns the first letter of the username.  This is a problem because the output of this function is used to remove user permissions on a mailbox.  I can't figure this out for the life of me.

Comment: Try `$menu.Add($i,$($rights[$i-1]))`. I think you forgot the dollar sign there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `(AuditSingleMailboxPermission -mbox $mbox).User` returns only one item, it will return a single object, not an array with length of one. Then, when you refer to `$rights[0]` it won't return the first object of an array, but the first character of the `String` representation of the object.

Casting to `Array` should fix the issue:

```
$rights = [Array](AuditSingleMailboxPermission -mbox $mbox).User
```

Generic example:

```
PS C:\> ("FOO", "BAR", "BAZ" | Select-Object -First 1)[0]
F

PS C:\> ("FOO", "BAR", "BAZ" | Select-Object -First 2)[0]
FOO
```

Comment: +1 for the explanation and an effective solution, but the PowerShell-idiomatic solution would be to use `@(AuditSingleMailboxPermission -mbox $mbox).User`, i.e., use of `@(...)`, the array-subexpression operator, which guarantees that a command's output is treated as an array, if it isn't already one.